# I want to print tab space in java. println("\t") doesn't work

Tags: java, string, eclipse, printing

[image]

I'm taking a java class rn and my teacher did this
System.out.println("A\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF");
to see A    B    C    D    E    F
but as you can see in my screenshot, it doesn't work..!!!
how can I solve this. pls help me

Comment: This might be visual issue caused by the font used in the _Console_ view (the non-ASCII characters are wider than the ASCII characters although it is a monospaced font). Does `System.out.println("A\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF")` work?

Comment: @howlger "A\t\B\tC..." haven't worked either, but you gave me a big hint. It was because of the font! I set 'Source Code Pro' font and it was the problem of spacing tab in console. I changed font and solved the problem. Thank you so much. It was a big help.

Answer (score 4):

```
you can give tab space in java easily. "\t" is the space sequence in java programming. Below i have given some examples:

Example 1:
```

System.out.print("Happy\tBirthday");

```
The output:

Happy Birthday

Example 2:
```

System.out.print("java\tprogramming");

```
The output:

Java programming.
```